# Solr, block updating of existing document

Tags: indexing, solr, duplicates, document

When a document is sent to solr and such document already exists in the index (by its ID) then the new one replaces old one.

But I don't want to automatically replace documents. Just ignore and proceed to the next. How can I configure solr.

Of course I can query solr to check if it has the document already but it's bad for me since I do bulk updates and this will complicate the process and increase amount of request.

So are there any ways to configure solr to ignore duplicates?

Comment: Have you read my updated answer? Was it useful?

Comment: yes it was useful. thanks for your attention and help. I resolved the issue by implementing simple updatehandler which discards new existing docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable the automatic overwriting of documents with the same uniqueIndex specifying the attribute `overwrite="false"` within the add element while you send documents to the `UpdateHandler`. Have a look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages).

```
<add overwrite="false">
    <doc>
        <field name="id">id</field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

Anyway **this allows to have duplicate documents into solr**, instead of skipping new documents with same id of existing ones. I don't think this is your desired behaviour.

I think you should write your own [`UpdateHandler`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/update/UpdateHandler.html) or [`UpdateRequestProcessor`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor) or follow the suggestions you got from the [solr user mailing list](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/solr-keep-old-docs-td3613328.html).

Comment: can you give me an example of config? I cannot figure out where to put this setting.

Comment: it doesn't work in fact. I am using solr 3.1.0 and update docs using solj library. Tried both variants. What might be the case?

Comment: Good to know you're using solrj. Are you using the xml or the binary format?

Comment: it's probably binary format. I also put these setting to javabin request handler but it didn't help. So I am stuck. Alos I have tried adding this parameter to request in java but it doesn't help as well.

Comment: I'm really sorry, my first answer was wrong, I misunderstood the documentation. I corrected it according to what I tested. Sorry again.