# Add documents ignore existing

Tags: solr

I need a SOLR's solution like a feature "INSERT INOGRE" of MYSQL.

I have looked and tried

[Solr, block updating of existing document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494923/solr-block-updating-of-existing-document)

but this made two duplicated even the schema has `uniqueKey`

Comment: Solr does not support Ogres. You may be able to figure out a solution using Trolls.

Answer (score 0):

Solr update XML has an "overwrite" option that specifies whether new documents should overwrite existing ones. The default is to overwrite, but you can disable this behavior. From the [Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22add.22):

> overwrite = "true" | "false" — default is "true", meaning newer documents will replace previously added documents with the same uniqueKey.

This would be a attribute of the "add" element in Solr update XML, ie

```
<add overwrite="false">
   <doc>
      ....
    </doc>
</add>
```